# Is there a better way to write this in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have this code, but there must be a better efficient to write it:

```
rt= RealTrans;
rtsize=size(rt);
rtrows=rtsize(1);
Relative_Axis_Moves=[rt(1,1) rt(1,2) rt(1,3) rt(1,4) rt(1,5);
rt(2:rtrows,1)-rt(1:rtrows-1,1) rt(2:rtrows,2)-rt(1:rtrows-1,2)
rt(2:rtrows,3)-rt(1:rtrows-1,3) rt(2:rtrows,4)-rt(1:rtrows-1,4)
rt(2:rtrows,5)-rt(1:rtrows-1,5)];
```

There are two rows in the matrix. The first row ends at `rt(1,5)`.

I also have the following code:

```
p1size=size(p1); 
p1rows=p1size(1); 
flank_edge_point=[0 0 0; p1(2:p1rows,2)-p1(1:p1rows-1,2) xy(2:p1rows,1)-xy(1:p1rows-1,1) xy(2:p1rows,2)-xy(1:p1rows-1,2); 0 0 xy(p1rows,2)];
```

How do i get `xy(p1rows,2)` value in matlab without `p1rows`?

I also have the code below which relies on the number of rows:

`RAMrow=size(Relative_Axis_Moves);

    RAMrow=RAMrow(1);

    for i=1:RAMrow

       L(i)=  norm(Relative_Axis_Moves(i,:));

    end

    L=L';

    L(RAMrow+1)= 0;`

Any way to write this code more succinctly and efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I formatted the code IMHO to more readable one. Feel free to ignore it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, there will be more than two rows in `Relative_Axis_Moves`, since the differences in the second row evaluate to arrays.

Anyway, a compact way of writing this is

```
Relative_Axis_Moves = [RealTrans(1,1:5);diff(RealTrans(:,1:5),1,1)];
```

Comment: @Venkat: In future, please update your question with any code that you'd like to add. The question provides better formatting and is easier to read than in the comments. I've updated the text for you this time.